# How to make all SKcenes the same size No matter what generation iPhone

Tags: xcode, swift, layout, sprite-kit, gamekit

In my ViewController I have this that scales the scene. the problem is that when someone plays the game with a iPhone 4s. The images aren't the same size. as when i test it on my iPhone. how do i fix this

```
 if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false
        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the images not being the same size, can you elaborate?  Is it that when you play the game, not all the nodes are visible?  This is sort of indicated by the title of the question.  If so, have you tried making `scene.scaleMode = .Fill` instead of `.AspectFill`?

Comment: No I had a friend test my app on a smaller phone and hey took a screen shot and sent it to me. When I saw it the game didn't look the same

Comment: maybe you could show us a screen shot of what you are looking for, and the one your friend took?  Again, we don't know how it didn't look the same, there could be a number of reasons, depending on the code.  My guess so far is that it is somewhere else in your code, as I used the code that you posted before.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to adjust the size of the scene - you want to adjust the scale of the nodes.

```
let scale = frame.width/667
node.setScale(scale)
```

Change the 667 to the width of the device in which it looks correct.